# Write ® to csv with csv.writer

Tags: python, csv, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to write strings with '®' to a csv file:

```
csvfile  = open(destination, "wb")
csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, delimiter='\t')
for row in data:
    csv_writer.writerow(row)

csvfile.close()
```

and row looks like this:

```
[123, "str", "str2 ®"]
```

The strings I'm trying to write to csv is retrieved from xml, which I believe is encoded to utf-8.

I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ec2-user/django/app/models.py", line 94, in import_data
    load_to_csv(out, out_data)
  File "/home/ec2-user/django/utils/util.py", line 90, in load_to_csv
    csv_writer.writerow(row)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xae' in position 66: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Then I tried to encode the string to utf-8:

```
csvfile  = open(destination, "wb")
csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, delimiter='\t')
for row in data:
    for i, r in enumerate(row):
        if type(r) is str:
            row[i] = r.encode('utf-8')
    csv_writer.writerow(row)

csvfile.close()
```

But I still get the same error.. Could anyone help? Have been stuck for a while..

Comment: Are you sure you have `"str2 ®"` and not `u"str2 ®"`?

Comment: Hi @MartijnPieters, this is what it looks like in xml file:`<quals>DVS®</quals>`. and this is the `print row` before `r.encode`: `[123, True, u'DVS\xae']`. Thanks!

Comment: If you are parsing XML python gives you Unicode strings. If you were to print your `row` lists, you'd see `[123, u"str", u"str2 ®"]`.

Comment: By the way, type checking should be done with `isinstance()` instead of type comparison (and definitely not with `is`), if at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a *Unicode* value, not a byte string. Encode those:

```
for row in data:
    row = [c.encode('utf8') if isinstance(c, unicode) else c for c in row]:
    csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: OK. It works well! Thanks very much! BTW, how could I know if my string is byte or unicode?

Comment: Oh yes! I was thinking why the string was unicode not byte.. But anyway, you are right! Thanks! ;)